# SQL Query to get Expiry date

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have columns `Issue Date` and `Valid for`:

- `Issue Date` is the issue date of certification
- `Valid For` (type `INT`) is the duration (number of years) of how long the certificate is valid for

I'm looking to get the exact expiry date.

Thanks

Screenshot of the table with sample data:

[image: pic]

Comment: Please be more precise: What does the column "valid for" exactly mean? Should the calculation just be issue_date + 99 days or + 5 days according to your screenshot? Why is the column not defined as integer? Which are possible entries? And please also show the expected outcome and what you tried so far.

Comment: What **datatypes** are those two columns? And what does "Valid for" signify - days? Months? Years? Seconds?

Comment: @marc_s Valid for is Number of years and the data type is INT

Comment: If the data type is INT, you should check why you are not seeing the values as int according to your screenshot. To calculate the year, I think there will no better way than Paul explained in his good answer. Just use DATEADD with year. So in my opinion, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has a simple function to add a number of time units to a date: **[DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (datepart , number , date )**

e.g. IF [Valid For] represents a number of days

```
select
     [Issue Date]
   , [Valid For]
   , dateadd(day,[Valid For],[Issue Date]) as [Valid To Date]
from yourtable
```

The first parameter to that function is the "datepart" i.e. the appropriate time unit (such as: second, hour, day, week, month) that the column [Valid For] represents. The second parameter is treated as an integer (any decimal value is ignored).

So, choose the appropriate "datepart" that satisfies the intended meaning of the number held in [Valid For] in the dateadd() function. Refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for details of the function.

Comment: This is a really good explanation of the dateadd function, but we still don't know if this is intended here. Since the column "valid_for" seems to be no integer, I guess as example following your propose and add 1.75 days or 2.23 days to the issue date will work without getting an error message, but the outcome will likely not be the expected one ;) In best case, not defining the column as integer was just a blunder and your idea is quite perfect. It would be very nice if the author answers this.

Comment: Utterly agree! That is why I mention that any decimal part would be ignored. It does appear that the data is always equivalent to an integer and could be cast to integer as well). Ideally @suhaspaunikar would identify what time unit [Valid For] represents and that that column was an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`dateadd(minute,convert(int,1440*[Valid For]),[Issue Date])`